# What's the difference between read() and getc()

Tags: c++, c

I have two code segments:

```
while((n=read(0,buf,BUFFSIZE))>0)
    if(write(1,buf,n)!=n)
        err_sys("write error");


while((c=getc(stdin))!=EOF)
    if(putc(c,stdout)==EOF)
        err_sys("write error");
```

Some sayings on internet make me confused. I know that standard I/O does buffering automatically, but I have passed a buf to `read()`, so `read()` is also doing buffering, right? And it seems that `getc()` read data char by char, how much data will the buffer have before sending all the data out?

Thanks

Comment: `read` is an operating system function, `getc` is a Standard C macro.  It's up to your compiler (technically, the C standard library implementation used by your compiler) as to whether it implements `getc` etc. via underlying calls to `read`, or does something else.

Comment: `getc` is a standard C function, not a macro.  (In C, all functions can be implemented as macros, under certain conditions.  In C++, this is not allowed; something like `struct X { int getc(); };` is required to compile as expected, and `X::getc` is a different function from `::getc` (or `std::getc`, if you've included `<cstdio>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While both functions can be used to read from a file, they are very different. First of all on many systems `read` is a lower-level function, and may even be a system call directly into the OS. The `read` function also isn't standard C or C++, it's part of e.g. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html). It also can read arbitrarily sized blocks, not only one byte at a time. There's no buffering (except maybe at the OS/kernel level), and it doesn't differ between "binary" and "text" data. And on POSIX systems, where `read` is a system call, it can be used to read from all kind of devices and not only files.

The `getc` function is a higher level function. It usually uses buffered input (so input is read in blocks into a buffer, sometimes by using `read`, and the `getc` function gets its characters from that buffer). It also only returns a single characters at a time. It's also part of the C and C++ specifications as part of the standard library. Also, there may be conversions of the data read and the data returned by the function, depending on if the file was opened in text or binary mode.

Another difference is that `read` is also always a function, while `getc` might be a preprocessor macro.

Comparing `read` and `getc` doesn't really make much sense, more sense would be comparing `read` with [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

Comment: Can you clarify the "only reads characters reliably, and not binary data" part ?

Comment: @cnicutar Removed that part

Comment: "`getc` may be a preprocessor macro": Only in C, not in C++.
And even as a macro, the function must be present, so that `int
(*pf)( FILE* ) = &getc;` will work.

Comment: @cnicutar It depends on how the file was opened.  In text mode, `getc` is only guaranteed to be able to read text.  (Since he's comparing with `read`, however, we can suppose Unix, in which case text mode is identical to binary, and you can read anything.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I just checked the C++11 specification and it doesn't mention it anywhere, just that it's part of `<cstdio>`. While I haven't read all of the C specification, it's the only one I know of that is (in a way) said that it may be implemented as a macro. Probably because many historical implementations had it as a macro.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Can I understand this like: getc() reads from a buffer which is full of data from the file, while read() reads from the file directly?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg C++(11, but the same text was present in
earlier versions), §17.6.1.2/6: "Names that are defined as
functions in C shall be defined as functions in the C++ standard
library".  And C(11, but unchanged from earlier versions),
§7.1.4/1 "Any function declared in a header may be additionally
implemented as a function-like macro defined in the
header,[...]".  The special text for `getc` gives the
implementation additional latitude if it is implemented as
a macro; other functions, even when implemented as a macro, may
evaluate each argument expression only once.

Comment: Just for the record: the OP doesn't really specify what he means by `read`.  _If_ it is the Posix function (which I suppose), then all Unix kernels I know do buffer (and when reading from a file, the system _must_ buffer).  If it's not the Posix function, it might very well distinguish between text and binary.  (Some early implementations of C under MS-DOS provided a `read` which did distinguish.)